# How do I upload a pdf from a Django HTTP object to google drive

Tags: python, django, google-drive-api, pisa

I use pisa to create pdf documents to render to the user:

```
response = HttpResponse()
pisa.CreatePDF(src=html, dest=response, show_error_as_pdf=True)
return response
```

response.content contains the pdf. I've used the dropbox-python sdk to do this:

```
dropbox_client.put_file(folder_path, response.content)
```

It seems to understand response.content as a pdf and uploads the file correctly

I need to do the same thing with the google-drive-python-api. This reference (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) shows a basic method, but MediaFileUpload seems to look for a physical file. There is MediaIoBaseUpload also but it doesn't seem to accept response.content. I'm not very familiar with file/i/o stuff, so I listed everything from django to dropbox to G-Drive here, hoping it would clarify my use; hopefully I didn't confuse matters.

Answer (score 2):

The `apiclient.http` file from the python Google API toolkit, contains the `MediaIoBaseUpload` object that does exactly what you need.

Only that it expects a file handle or something that behaves like file handle (the `fh` parameter). You're in luck: that's exactly what the [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) module is for:

```
import StringIO # You could try importing cStringIO which gives better performance
fh = StringIO.StringIO(response.content)
media = MediaIoBaseUpload(fh, mimetype='some/mimetype')
# See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert for the rest
```

---

`MediaInMemoryUpload` would do the trick too, but it's deprecated now.

Comment: This makes sense to me but its not working: I get: UnicodeDecodeError at /url/. 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 353: ordinal not in range(128). I know my pdf_function works because a url to that view generates a valid pdf and i use the result to upload to dropbox which has a valid pdf. I tried MediaInMemoryUpload which didn't throw an error but created a document that adobe wouldn't open.

Comment: @rsp This is just an encoding error. [The `StringIO` documentation makes it pretty clear what is accepted as input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO). You should `.decode('utf-8')` (or whatever encoding you're using) your `response.content` before passing it to `StringIO.StringIO`.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried your method and also passed 'encoding="UTF-8"' to the CreatePDF function, to be explicit. Now I get 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 11: invalid start byte. Also tried: When I generate the pdf I saved that as a file. then I used MediaFileUpload with that filename and the pdf is uploaded and opens perfectly. I'm at a loss despite trying several methods. It seems like saving a file would cause problems since a different function creates the pdf from the one that uploads, etc. I don't know if it matters that my file has images?

Comment: @rsp Could you try using `io.BytesIO`?

Comment: same problem. I can do: temp = StringIO.StringIO(response.content), f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False), f.write(temp.getvalue())   f.close(), and then use MediaFileUpload with f.name. It seems like a lot of extra steps and inefficient but it works perfectly.